# How to call C# class method from link in Outlook email?

Tags: c#, outlook, href

In my Class1 oMsg.HTMLBody I want to give a reference so that DBConnectivity.cs class connectivity() method is called on click of link in the email sent. Can you please help with that.

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Outlook_SendMailItem
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the Outlook application by using inline initialization.
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                //Create the new message by using the simplest approach.
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                //Add a recipient.
                // TODO: Change the following recipient where appropriate.
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oMsg.Recipients.Add("aman.agarwal4@cognizant.com");
                oRecip.Resolve();

                //Set the basic properties.
                oMsg.Subject = "This is the subject of the test message";
                oMsg.HTMLBody = "<a href=\"what_is_required_here\">Approve</a><pre>    </pre><a href=\"what_is_required_here\">Reject</a>";

                // Add an attachment.
                // TODO: change file path where appropriate
                String sSource = "C:\\Users\\461023\\Desktop\\Servlets.txt";
                String sDisplayName = "MyFirstAttachment";
                int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(sSource, iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

                // If you want to, display the message.
                // oMsg.Display(true);  //modal

                //Send the message.
                oMsg.Save();
                ((Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();

                //Explicitly release objects.
                oRecip = null;
                oAttach = null;
                oMsg = null;
                oApp = null;
            }

            // Simple error handler.
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught: ", e);
            }

            //Default return value.
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

DBConnectivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SendEmail
{
    class DBConnectivity
    {
        public void connectivity()
        {
            string query = "Update Leaves Set status = @status where emailid = @emailid";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query , connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", "approved");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("emailid", "email_id");

                int affected_rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing that. I'd create a php script and upload it online, and redirect the user to this page whenever he clicks on Approve/Reject.

Comment: can you please tell how ?

Comment: Something along the lines of `oMsg.HTMLBody = "<a href=\"http:\\yourpage.com?accepted=1\">Approve</a><pre>    </pre><a href=\"http:\\yourpage.com?accepted=0\">Reject</a>";` Search online for php scripts, it is fairly easy to execute a sql command with php

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it this way, but you can use PHP to do that:

```
// Connect to mssql server 
$connection = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot connect to server");

// Select a database 
$db = mssql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die("Cannot select database");

// Get the status and execute the query
$query = 'UPDATE Leaves SET status = ' . $_GET['status'] . ' WHERE emailid = @emailid'; 
$result = mssql_query($query);

// Close the connection 
mssql_close($connection);
```

Put this script in a php file and host it online. Then you can use it like this:

```
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<a href=\"http://yourpage.com?status=1\">Approve</a><pre> </pre><a href=\"http:///yourpage.com?status=0\">Reject</a>";
```

Comment: it is not a web application but a simple console application. So I wont be able to do something like http://yourpage.com

Comment: That is the body of the email. You can put whatever you want there.

Comment: I thnik i am doing something wrong. Please check we need to keep the script in .php file. And what should be the name in place of http://yourpage.com. Is it Project name?

Comment: is there any other approach also for doing this task ? A betterr one !!

Comment: No it's not project name, it's the url of the hosted php script. I'm afraid there is no better solution. Your client will open his mail through his webmail client, there is no way to do any C# action. The only thing you can do is reach a page on the internet (everybody has access to it) so it can execute your script.